# ctags: error while loading shared libraries: libgpm.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ctags

I have used ctags command to generate tags to traverse in vi editor. Unfortunately 
a shared library is not available. how to fix this problem, i don't want to install the library as i'm working on a shared development environment.

Please check the below error.

ctags: error while loading shared libraries: libgpm.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Comment: `ctags` normally doesn't depend on `gpm`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/where/libgpm.so/is/located`
And then start it again.